# Nominal operating fan speed in Ubuntu 15.04 on Dell 3521 Inspiron

Tags: dell, fancontrol

I find the laptop getting heated up, so when i do the xsensors it shows me fan2 speed as 78000-90000. Core temperatures are near 51 celsius and odd. fan1 speed is not shown in the xsensors. Please suggest me some solution to rectify this problem.

Comment: I run a dell 5521 - There are a couple of items that I would like to know if you have installed:  TLP or LapTop tools (they are mutually exclusive), and intel_microcode?

Comment: No i haven't installed any of those explicitly.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you expect to see or happen?

Comment: I find the laptop getting heated up. So im looking at a solution which can reduce the heat, because this will reduce the life of the hardware components on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not have active power management built-in, sufficient for laptops.  There are two solutions for the laptop power issues, TLP and laptop-mode-tools.  I use TLP, and recommend that installation.  For Ubuntu 15.04, a PPA must be added (TLP seems to be a core utility in 15.10).  To do this, open a terminal window (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get install -y tlp --install-suggests
```

There is a configuration file which can be customized for tlp, although the defaults work quite well.  A reboot is required.  Information about TLP can be found at [this link](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html).

I also have installed intel-microcode and linux-firmware-nonfree.  The first includes updates to the microcode of the intel processors, and the second includes drivers which are not open-source, and required by some odd devices which may or may not be present on your system.  These two utilities can be added via the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: I tried the above. After rebooting the system, when i use xsensors or psensor to see the temperature, fan speeds, i still find only fan2, temperature of the cores. Fan speeds are around 81000 still, temperatures nearly 52 Celsius.

Comment: Wow - that's weird.  I've been running Ubuntu approx 3 year now, and since TLP, have not had a problem with the Dells. HPs are another story.  Is there a possibility that Fan1 is disconnected or inoperable?

Comment: When i do sudo sensors-detect  it shows "No" for most of the sensors and Success only for few !! Does that affect this sensing?

Comment: Or how do i check if the fan is disabled etc. I'm a newbie to linux.

Comment: Ok!! I have forgot to give the command sudo tlp start. Now the fan speed is showing 15300 and temperatures of the cores around 45 Celsius. But any idea how do i enable/check the other fan, sensors.

Comment: ad@ad-dell-3521:~$ psensor
[2015-10-14T18:16:05] [ERR] lmsensor: Cannot get value of subfeature temp2_input: Can't read.
[2015-10-14T18:16:05] [ERR] lmsensor: Cannot get value of subfeature temp1_input: Can't read.
[2015-10-14T18:16:05] [ERR] nvctrl: Failed to retrieve NVIDIA information.                                                                                                                                                This is what it shows up in my terminal when i give the command psensor.

Comment: I just ran psensor, and my computer only shows fan2 as well.  A quick glance at the documents from Dell, indicates that there is only a single fan, apparently names fan2.  A temp of 50 C is not too hot, IMHO.  Many sites indicate 45-50 being quite normal, 60 on the high side.  The old HP pavilions I use to deal with, regularily ran around 90, at which point the graphics chips would become de-soldered.

Comment: Ok. but in some other thread in askubuntu i found the psensor revealing a lot many parameters for different peripherals, but in my case it shows up only quite a handful of them. Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: I believe that is a limitation of the machine itself - not all of our computers have sensors that are intelligent...